# Can you set a custom group to "Show In Menu" using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I've looked through the Group object properties and Add method of the TaskGroups object. I've also searched the Application object for a method or property that works, but I can't find it. This seems simple, but after 3 days still can't figure it out....

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in MS-Project ? OR VBA ?

Comment: VBA. It's pretty easy in MS Project :)